# WPF Geometry Rotatation Animation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, rotation

I would like to rotate my custom shape with an animation.
When i run my application i get this message in my immediate window:

> BindingExpression path error: 'Angle' property not found on 'object'
>   ''MatrixTransform' (HashCode=16493105)'. null

**My shape**

```
Dim myPointerPath = New Path()
    Dim myPointerPathGeometry = New PathGeometry()
    Dim myPointerPathFigure = New PathFigure()
    Dim leftLine As New LineSegment
    Dim rightLine As New LineSegment

    myPointerPathFigure.StartPoint = New Point(Me.left + (Me.width / 2), Me.top + (Me.width / 60))

    leftLine.Point = New Point(Me.left * 1.8, Me.top)
    rightLine.Point = New Point(Me.left + (Me.width / 2), Me.top - Me.width / 60)

    myPointerPathFigure.Segments.Add(leftLine)
    myPointerPathFigure.Segments.Add(rightLine)
    myPointerPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPointerPathFigure)
    myPointerPath.Data = myPointerPathGeometry
    myPointerPath.Stroke = Me.pointerColor
    myPointerPath.Fill = Me.pointerColor

    myCanvas.Children.Add(myPointerPath)

    Me.pointerShape = myPointerPathGeometry
```

**For a single line shape, this code would animate the rotation:**

```
Public Sub drawPointerAtValue(ByVal p_value As Double)

    Dim rotator = New RotateTransform(p_value)
    Dim da = New DoubleAnimation(0, 180, New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
    Dim storyboard = New Storyboard()

    rotator.CenterX = pointerLine.X1
    rotator.CenterY = pointerLine.Y1

    storyboard.Children.Add(da)
    storyboard.SetTarget(da, pointerLine)
    storyboard.Duration = da.Duration
    storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, New PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"))
    storyboard.AccelerationRatio = 0.2
    storyboard.DecelerationRatio = 0.2

    da.to = p_value
    storyboard.Begin()
End Sub
```

**this is the code for the rotation animation of my custom shape (2 line shapes)**

```
Public Sub rotateShape(ByVal p_value As Double)
        Dim rotator = New RotateTransform(p_value)
        Dim da = New DoubleAnimation(0, 180, New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
        Dim storyboard = New Storyboard()

        rotator.CenterX = Me.left + (Me.width / 2)
        rotator.CenterY = Me.top

        storyboard.Children.Add(da)
        storyboard.SetTarget(da, pointerShape)
        storyboard.Duration = da.Duration
        storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, New PropertyPath("Transform.Angle"))
        storyboard.AccelerationRatio = 0.2
        storyboard.DecelerationRatio = 0.2
            da.To = p_value
        storyboard.Begin()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually assign the RotateTransform to the `Transform` property of a Geometry? In rotateShape you don't seem to use `rotator` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the shape to a Polygon, instead of using a PathGeometry.

```
Dim rotator = New RotateTransform(Value)
    Dim da = New DoubleAnimation()
    Dim sb = New Storyboard()

    rotator.CenterX = centreX
    rotator.CenterY = centreY

    rotator.CenterX = centreX
    rotator.CenterY = centreY

    pointerShape.RenderTransform = rotator
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, Me.pointerShape)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, New PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Angle"))

    da.Duration = New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    da.to = toValue
    da.from = fromValue

    sb.AccelerationRatio = 0.2
    sb.DecelerationRatio = 0.2
    sb.Children.Add(da)
```